# Assembly Tasm Loop.noidea

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

Can you tell that this code is a loop?, even without declaring a loop below?

```
pool:
mov ah, 9
lea dx, shw_smthng
int 21h
jmp pool
```

Comment: Well there's clearly a jump instruction back to `pool`, so yes, it's a loop. Not sure what you mean by "declaring" a loop.

Comment: Loops are never "declared" anyway

Comment: what I mean of declare is this *loop pool*, xD

Comment: by the way, thanks!

Comment: That's not a "declaration", it's a special instruction (http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LOOP:LOOPcc.html) that's like `dec cx / jnz pool`.  Don't fall into the trap of thinking that the `loop` instruction is always the best (or only) way to write loops.  It's slow, so you normally shouldn't use it (unless optimizing for code-size instead of speed). 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently

Comment: @PeterCordes ah, now I get it, thanks!